# Unable to retrieve value returned from mysql function

Tags: sql, mysql, function

Since a week am working with MYSQL , got to execute the Stored Procedure as well as Views but Facing some problem retrieving the values returned from a function.
Here's the Function:

```
      CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GetProductIdsStringByEnquiryId`
         (
         InEnquiryId int
         ) RETURNS varchar(4000) CHARSET utf8
      BEGIN
        DECLARE InProductIds varchar(4000);
        DECLARE ProductId varchar(50);
        DECLARE x,y,z INT;
        DECLARE sp1_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ProductId FROM enquiryproductid where 
          EnquiryId=InEnquiryId;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET z = 1;
        SET InProductIds='';
        OPEN sp1_cursor;
        REPEAT
        FETCH sp1_cursor INTO ProductId;
        SETInProductIds=concat(InProductIds,ProductId,',');
        UNTIL (z=1)
        END REPEAT;
        CLOSE sp1_cursor;
       RETURN InProductIds ;
     END
```

I was initially working with SQL SERVER 2005, and the function which I have written in their I tried converting it as above in MYSQL, 
Here's the  SQL Function Code:

```
       CREATE function [dbo].[GetBranchIdsStringByEmployeeId]
        (
    @EmployeeId as integer
         )
       returns nvarchar(4000)
      as
      begin
  declare @BranchIds as nvarchar(4000)
  set @BranchIds=''
  if exists(select 1 from dbo.BranchEmployees where EmployeeId=@EmployeeId)
    begin
        select @BranchIds=@BranchIds+cast(BranchId as nvarchar(50))
                      +','   from dbo.BranchEmployees where EmployeeId=@EmployeeId
                       order by BranchId
    end
return @BranchIds
       end
```

Can anybody Please Let me know if the Function What I have written in MYSQL is in ProperManner or not? Please do help me out.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Not read fully through it, but few comments

Variable assignment in mysql uses `:=` (in `set @variable` it is ok to use `=`, in `select @variable:=@variable+1`)

Are you trying to

```
SELECT group_concat(BranchId)
FROM dbo.BranchEmployees
WHERE EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
```

?

Comment: Actually am trying to retrive the mutiple branchIds assigned to a particular employee. Is their a problem in the query?any other way of getting them...Please do let me know

Comment: @SUSH, examine http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat . This is mysql extension and gives you what you need (comma separated list of branchIDs assigned to particular employee, etc...) without resorting to SPs. On a completely different note - the fact that you are getting list of IDs suggests that you will use that in another query. That's usually not the right approach - you can get anything that you would get with IN with subqueries and/or a join.

Comment: Ya what you told is right, am using this function in a view to retrieve the multiple branches each separated with comma.